# How can I unshare "users" folder by default after each win 10 fresh installation?

Tags: security, networking

I use 2 laptops on same network and I realized by default after fresh install they both can access each other's users folder.

do I have to remember and unshare these folders at every fresh install or is there a way to by default share nothing in case a friend with his laptop will come and connect to my home network and I will have forgotten to unshare user folder which may contain some private info on my desktop
what is the solution?
thank you

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score -1):

you need to make sure that both accounts are not listed as administrator accounts. you can do this within control panel > user accounts > account type. however, if both NEED to be administrator, I don't think it's possible to not allow one to access the other, as they have administrative access to the whole computer.